# how to delete photo stream from ipad running ios 6?

Tags: ios, ipad, photo-stream

I have an older iPad 3 running iOS6 that I no longer use as my main device, and it is now dedicated to specific apps.  I no longer take photos or videos on it, so have no need for the Photo Stream feature on this device at all.

I have deactivated the feature, and accepted the "This will delete all photo stream content from your device" dialog.  However the photo stream content is still taking up more than 2GB on the device.  Nothing seems to actually give me that storage back again.

How can I reclaim the Photo Stream storage space on this device?

Comment: Have you restarted the iPad since you did that?

Comment: Oh yes, several times.

Comment: Where did you turn this feature off from? Make sure you didn't turn off iCloud Photos instead

Comment: Settings, Photos & Camera.  There is no iCloud Photos in iOS6.